# why my variable does not pass in the modal box

Tags: javascript, php

good evening
I have two sites the first in php and the second in wordpress

on the one in php i have a table with links

each link opens an article to wordpress

the link is in
$donnees["guid"]

I did some var_dump of $donnees["guid"]

the results are correct

Except when the modal opens

It's always the same value

```
<div class="col-md-1" style="border: solid; text-align: center;">  <?php var_dump( $donnees['guid']); //is ok ?>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" onclick="openModal (event,'')"> Open modal </button>
  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body"> Vous êtes sur le point d être redirigé pour visionner la sortie de pêche sur le nouveau site <?php var_dump( $donnees['guid']);  ?> </div>
        <div class="confirm-delete hide">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Confirmed</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          </div>
          <p>Il ce peux que la redirection prenne quelques secondes</p> <?php var_dump( $donnees['guid']);//is not ok  ?> <div class="modal-footer1">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="window.location.href = '
                            <?php echo ( $donnees['guid']);  ?>', '_blank';">ok </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="confirmDelete()">Ok on y va</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- The Modal -->
</div>
```

```
   function confirmDelete(){
  console.log("Deleting...");
  $('.modal-header, .modal-footer, .modal-body').addClass('hide');
  $('.confirm-delete').removeClass('hide');
  //$('#myModal').modal('hide');
}

function openModal(){
  $('.confirm-delete').addClass('hide');
  $('#myModal .modal-header, .modal-footer, .modal-body').removeClass('hide');
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
```

Comment: CSS is irrelevant as far as I can tell. Removed to simplify question.

Comment: Tip: Instead of these functions jammed in with `onclick`, use `$('.modal').on('click', function (ev) { ... })` to hook in events. It leads to much cleaner code. Plus, **use the event** and `this` context to open/hide or whatever, as in `$(this).toggle()` or with some kind of `parent()` selector to roll up to the thing you want to close.

Comment: Your `onclick` presumes `event` exists, which it does not. If you are going to use plain JavaScript handlers like `onclick`, it's best to specify *only* the function name and let the browser call it with the correct arguments.

Comment: Can you give the thing you want to disappear a class like `modal-dialog`? If so, `$(this).parents('.modal-dialog').toggle()` is all you need.

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Also for the explanation, but can you give me an example

Comment: @tadman Why would it not exist? It's a global variable `window.event` which is set by the browser prior to calling any event handler. (True, it's deprecated, but [every relevant browser still supports it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event#browser_compatibility) so that can't be the issue here.)

Comment: @CherryDT If you want to trust that, sure, but it seems ambiguous. It also messes up the `this` binding if you call it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the different ids for different modals or make the template

When you have a few tags with id="myModal" it will open the first modal every time

html:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" onclick="openModal ('#myModal1')"> Open modal </button>
  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal1">
```

js:

```
function openModal(eve, id){
  $('.confirm-delete').addClass('hide');
  $(id + ' .modal-header, .modal-footer, .modal-body').removeClass('hide');
  $(id).modal('show');
}
```

for next button it will be myModal2, myModal3 and etc.

**Upd, for last changes:**

html:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" onclick="openModal (event)"> Open modal </button>
  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal1">
```

js:

```
function openModal(eve){
  $('.confirm-delete').addClass('hide');
  $(eve.target).next().modal('show');
  $(eve.target).next().find('.modal-header, .modal-footer, .modal-body').removeClass('hide');
}
```

Comment: you have a few modals with id myModal. So when you try to find #myModal - it returns the first modal every time

Comment: Thank you for the answer

But it's not possible to realize I'm in a loop

Comment: Got it! Сompleted the answer. Is it fine now?

Comment: Many thanks for the solution

It works wonderfully

A thousand times thank you